# pthread POSIX C library detachstate

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix, libraries

I was asked from where do we know that when passing `NULL` as a second argument in `pthread_create()` function the thread is made joinable.

I mean, I know that man pages state so, but a justification in code was demanded.
I know that when `NULL` is passed in, default attributes are used:

`const struct pthread_attr *iattr = (struct pthread_attr *) attr;
   if (iattr == NULL)
     /* Is this the best idea?  On NUMA machines this could mean         accessing far-away memory.  */
     iattr = &default_attr;`

I know that it should be somewhere in the code of pthread library, but I don't know where exactly.

I know that the definition of `default_attr` is in pthread_create.c:

`static const struct pthread_attr default_attr = { /* Just some value > 0 which gets rounded to the nearest page size. */ .guardsize = 1, };`

http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_create.c;h=4fe0755079e5491ad360c3b4f26c182543a0bd6e;hb=HEAD#l457

but I do not know where is *exactly stated in the code* that this result in a joinable thread.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Again, as in your previous question there seems to be a lot of confusion where guarantees of a certain behavior of a program comes from. POSIX (and thus POSIX threads) is an international standard that regulates how a program that is written accordingly behaves. You wouldn't find the semantics of the `pthread_create` call in the code, but in the standard. Search for "opengroup" and "pthread_create" in your favorite search engine and you should find the official specification.

Comment: Ok, I see. But when my teacher is asking me about source code justification, what should I say ? I mean, I'm afraid that when I say that there's no code to justify, only POSIX specification and it's not the whole truth, that may result badly to me :)

Comment: don't be afraid of your teacher. If he makes such a request, he should specify what he means by a justification in code. Actually typically this here is a question that you should have asked him, not us.

Comment: "don't be afraid of your teacher" - good one. I wish I was. Unfortunately, he's the one to ask questions there.

Comment: That's really the wrong way around, he is a bad teacher then. Sure that you have to ask questions in exams, but the grounds on which you place these question should be clear and settled.

Comment: You know, I'm from Poland and the university is public, which means payed by the state and such term as "bad teacher" doesn't exist - in case you still want to study. Actually, he's one of the better - it seems that he was made teacher because he really knows something and not because his uncle is a professor there ... :) which apparently is quite common, trust me. And exam will be in two weeks in case I'm fortunate :)

Comment: Oh, and any questions can be always interpreted as 'undermining the authority of the researcher' or be at least a bit stressful... and 'researchers' don't need no stress! :) and they don't need competitors in the labor market as well :)

Comment: Hm, thank you very much for your frank estimation what a researcher and a university teacher is. I hope that in general my Polish colleagues still behave a bit differently than you describe, and that it is just the bad sample that you encountered that makes you think like that. At least we researchers here in public service in France are highly motivated and are happy about students that ask intelligent questions :)

Comment: Sorry for my English, maybe these are not so accurate job titles. But I can assure you that at least one lecturer per term spends too much time commenting on student's intellectual level, and once you become researcher, only another researcher can harm you :) no denying there are passionate lecturers happy to answer questions, but most of them seem to be reacting defensive. Another rather the fact is that salaries at university are low, especially for young employees, at least in the field of computer science and electronics... but you get the power and job security. Thanks for your effort! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, from the code you pasted you can see that `default_attr` contains zeroes in almost all fields (there's no such thing as a half-initialized variable in C: if you only initialize some fields, the others are set to 0).

Second, [`pthread_create`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_create.c;h=4fe0755079e5491ad360c3b4f26c182543a0bd6e;hb=HEAD#l491) contains this code:

```
/* Initialize the field for the ID of the thread which is waiting
   for us.  This is a self-reference in case the thread is created
   detached.  */
pd->joinid = iattr->flags & ATTR_FLAG_DETACHSTATE ? pd : NULL;
```

This line checks whether `iattr->flags` has the `ATTR_FLAG_DETACHSTATE` bit set, which (for `default_attr`) it doesn't because `default_attr.flags` is 0. Thus it sets `pd->joinid` to `NULL` and not to `pd` as for detached threads.

(Note that this answer only applies to GNU glibc and not to POSIX pthreads in general.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Most probably that's the answer I have been looking for.